# Zend Framework Architecture

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi Need to confirm Zend Framework Hierarchy of Objects ,

- `Zend_Application` has a Property Object Bootstrap
- Bootstrap has a Property Object `Zend_Controller_Front` inside
- `Zend_Controller_Front` has nested Objects like Request , Response , Plugins and also a 
  dispatcher() method through dispatcher Interface
- When `Zend_Front_Controller`'s `dispatch()` method is called a Controller Method is called as viewed in Request Object.
- Now, `Zend_Controller_Action` has a Variable called `$view` which stores the Name of the PHTML Script
- Now , `Zend_Controller_Action` has a render() which basically does include() for the given PHTML Script
- When everything is done by PHP Interpretor , the Response comes back to Browser

Did I get it right , If not please correct

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained at

- [Zend_Controller Basics](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.basics.html) and
- [Zend Framework MVC Request Lifecycle](http://devzone.zend.com/article/11978) and
- [Zend Framework Dispatch Workflow](http://www.slideshare.net/polleywong/zend-framework-dispatch-workflow)

Usually I do not like pointing to external resources without giving a few words to it, but to explain what's going on is too much to type in my own words, so bear with me on this one.

If the explanation at the given links dont suffice, you could install XDebug and step through the execution flow if you want to know all the nittygritty details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit less orthodox view on [how zend framework application could be architectured](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/how-to-structure-a-zend-framework-application-and-manage-internal-dependencies).