# Zend Framework 1 - difference between View and Response-Object's body

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm learning to use Zend Framework 1 but I don't understand the difference between these two elements.
I studied from the theory that the Front-Controller gets the Request-Object and using the routing/dispatching process sends the Response-Object, whose body contains HTML code for the browser...
BUT making a simple "helloZend" application I figured out that every time an ActionController's action is called, his view (aka HTML code) is automatically rendered.

Comment: Related: [Zend Framework Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609176/zend-framework-architecture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, the Response object represents an HTTP response. As such, it primarily concerns itself with the HTTP response headers (status code, Content-type, etc) and the response body (in the case of an HTML page requested by a browser, for example, the HTML markup that the browser will eventually render). This is why the Response object has methods for manipulating the headers and the body.

The View object is primarily concerned with building up the content that will eventually go into the Response body. Of course, View objects can be used for lots of other purposes; for example, composing email messages from templates. But in the case of an HTTP request being serviced in the standard way by a ZF1 application, the content that comes from the view is eventually placed into the Response body by the framework. Specifically, a View object is typically created/configured during bootstrap and it is eventually made available to the developer in the controller as:

```
$this->view
```

In your controller, when you add data into the view using:

```
$this->view->someKey = 'someValue';
```

that data is available in your view-script, which is rendered and added into the View object.

At the end of the request processing pipeline, the framework passes the rendering of the view into the body of the Response object and the Response knows how to render itself in an HTTP-compliant way, providing the client (typically a browser) with a payload formatted as he would expect it.